# How can I fix the messed up python package environment of my laptop?

Tags: python, package, anaconda, python-venv

I used to work with anaconda jupyter notebook last semester for my AI course. I installed and used a lot of packages (globally - stupid mistake, i know) using anaconda. Sometime towards the end of the semester, all my packages just stopped working, and even deleting and reinstalling them didn't work. i left it and moved on, uninstalled anaconda, and thought it was fine.

now, i installed opencv and numpy globally and neither VScode nor Pycharm see it. the packages don't work. it reminded me of my previous semesters' issues and i realized that now, my package-installing space is most likely screwed. how do I reset it all and fix it? and how should I go about installing packages in the future?

I tried resetting everything and uninstalling everything from the root folder, tried uninstalling anaconda, but to no avail. i want to revert everything to before i started this mess.

i am prepared to offer screenshots in case you need to better understand the issue.

Comment: Use `conda env list` to get a list of environments and their actual location in your system. Then, you can delete them one by one using `conda env remove -n ENV_NAME`. That should do most of the "cleaning". Next, for each new project, you should create a fresh new env. Check this for some more info https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-started-with-python-environments-using-conda-32e9f2779307

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To start fresh and fix the issues with your package management in Python, especially after installing packages globally using Anaconda, you can take the following steps:

Resetting Python Environment:
Uninstall Anaconda:

Ensure that Anaconda is completely uninstalled from your system. You can follow the official Anaconda uninstallation instructions for your operating system.
Resetting Python Environment:

Remove any remaining traces of Anaconda and Python from your system by deleting Anaconda-related folders and removing Anaconda/Python paths from your system variables.
Reinstall Python:

Download and install the latest version of Python from the official Python website. This will provide you with a clean Python environment.
Virtual Environments:

Create a virtual environment for your projects using venv or virtualenv . This allows you to install packages for each project separately without affecting the global environment.
Package Management:

Install packages using the package manager pip within your virtual environments. Activate the desired environment and use pip install package-name to install packages locally for that specific project.
Example Workflow for Creating Virtual Environment and Installing Packages:

```
# Create a new virtual environment
python -m venv myenv

# Activate the virtual environment
# On Windows
myenv\Scripts\activate
# On macOS or Linux
source myenv/bin/activate

# Install required packages (e.g., opencv and numpy)
pip install opencv-python numpy

# Work on your project within this virtual environment

# Deactivate the virtual environment once you are done
deactivate
```

By following these steps and working within isolated virtual environments for your projects, you can avoid the issues caused by global package installations and ensure a clean and organized Python development environment.

Feel free to ask if you need further clarification or encounter any issues during the process!

Comment: "removing Anaconda/Python paths from your system variables", what does that mean? how can I do that? I am currently uninstalling Anaconda and deleted all related folders.

Comment: remove Python and Anaconda paths from your Environment Variables, if you are using Windows

Comment: @LeenaA I answered your question above, if you use any OS other than Windows. let me know. I will let you know what to do.

Comment: Thank you very much! Question though; when i create a virtual environment (in your example "myenv") do I create the python files inside myenv or in the same directory as myenv?

Comment: It's not important where you create your python files. just remember to activate that virtualenv. your files can be anywhere